# Write to a file without overwriting the existing data within that file

Tags: java, filewriter

I have a filewriter that takes String data from the user and writes it on the file. But the filewriter replaces the already existing data in that file. How do I prevent it from doing it? I just want to keep adding information without writing over something.

Here is the code

```
    String info = scan.nextLine();
    File myFile = new File ("/home/greg/workspace/Mavericks/fred.txt");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter (myFile);
    writer.write(register);
    writer.flush();
```

Thanks. I fixed that. Now I just want to make the writer write using spaces. When I write to the file it just keeps writing within the same line.

Comment: So you want to write every time to a new line?

Comment: Add '\n' after each line.

Comment: And don't forget to do writer.close();

Comment: Or if you are using BufferedWriter, there is a newLine() method.

Comment: The newLine method worked perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use second parameter of FileWriter, which is defining if you want to append or not. Just set it to `true`.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                sFileName, true));
```

Add `\n` after each line.

Answer (score 1):

You need use the boolean value `true`. From docs

```
public FileWriter(String fileName,
          boolean append)
           throws IOException
```

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean
>   indicating whether or not to append the data written.

**Parameters:**

`fileName` - String The system-dependent filename.

`append` - boolean if true, then data will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
new FileWriter(myFile, true)
```

The second parameter is for appending.

Answer (score 0):

Api:

```
FileWriter(File file, boolean append)
```

Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

FileWriter has an optional boolean in the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29), which declares if it should be appended or not.

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(..., true)
```

Answer (score -1):

BufferedWriter bw = new  BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename ,true));